# Como atualizar uma linha na tabela com ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

A ideia é clicar no botão válidar ou inválidar e atualizar aquela linha na table, alterando a classe do botão para a respectiva situação `class: valido` ou `class: invalido` com ajax.

Minha dificuldade é como tratar os dados do `response` no e atualizar a linha do `HTML` .

Script

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "updateTelefone.php
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {

  },
  success: function(response) {

  }


}


});
```

HTML

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>codigo</th>
      <th>descricao</th>
      <th>Ação</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>11 5589-0000</td>
      <td>
        <button id="valido" class="sem-validacao">Válido</button>
        <button id="invalido" class="sem-validacao">Inválido</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você só quer alterar a classe do botão clicado após o retorno do AJAX, então não precisa receber nenhum retorno `response`. A única coisa que você precisa enviar no AJAX é o `id` da linha (que suponho ser a coluna `código` da tabela, que é a primeira `td`.) e uma informação se é "válido" ou "inválido".

Primeiro que você não deve colocar `id="valido"` e `id="invalido"` nos botões, porque você teria que repetir essas `id`'s nos outros botões das outras linhas, e repetir `id` é incorreto no HTML. Então não as use. Em vez disso, acrescente uma classe apenas nos botões "Válido", para diferenciar dos botões "Inválido". Eu coloquei a classe `.val`, ficando assim:

```
                ↓
<button class="val sem-validacao">Válido</button>
<button class="sem-validacao">Inválido</button>
```

Como você não irá precisar de nenhum dado retornado do AJAX, não precisa colocar `response` na função do `success`, e não precisa também da opção `dataType: 'json',`. Também não precisa colocar `type: 'get',`, pois o `type` do `$.ajax` já é `get` por padrão.

Basta então, após o AJAX ser concluído (função do `success`) verificar se o botão clicado possui a classe `.val`, para inserir nele a classe `.valido` ou `.invalido`.

O código irá ficar desta forma (veja comentários explicativos):

```
// pega o click nos botões pela classe .sem-validacao
$(".sem-validacao").on("click", function(){

   var $this = $(this); // variável para guardar o botão clicado

   // variável que irá ser "true" se o botão clicado tiver a classe .val
   // ou "false" se não tiver
   var valido = $this.hasClass("val");

   $.ajax({
      url: "updateTelefone.php",
      data: {
         id: $this         // botão clicado
            .closest("tr") // pega a linha do botão
            .find("td")    // busca uma coluna
            .first()       // a primeira coluna
            .text()        // pega o texto da coluna
            .trim(),       // remove espaços

         v: valido         // envia "true" ou "false"
      },
      success: function(){
         $this // botão clicado
         .addClass( valido ? "valido" : "invalido" ); // adiciona uma das classes
      }
   });
});
```

Repare que o AJAX envia duas variáveis para o PHP: `id` e `v` (essas variáveis você pode nomear como quiser). No PHP você irá pegar ambas com `$_GET['id']` e `$_GET['v']`.

O `$_GET['id']` será a `id` do telefone, e o `$_GET['v']` será `true` ou `false`, que você precisará como informação para atualizar o banco de dados.

Comment: Sam, fico muito agradecido pela dica.  Adequei seu código a minha necessidade e deu certo.

Answer (score 3):

O **response** vai trazer o os dados de retorno do **get** na url **updateTelefone.php**, como  vi que o **dataType:** é **json** então o retorno vai vir nesse formato.

Quando o request acontece sem erros ele vai chamar como callback a função que você passar no **success**, caso você queira ter o callback em caso de erro, você deve adicionar uma função para a propriedade **error**.

Para detalhar melhor a resposta precisaria saber como seria o retorno, mas vou colocar um exemplo aqui.

ex: Vamos supor que o retorno seria {OK:true} para o caso de válido e {OK:false} para inválido.

```
if(response.OK) {
     $("#valido").show();
     $("#invalido").hide();
}
else {
     $("#valido").hide();
     $("#invalido").show();
}
```

edit 1:

se deseja atualizar todos os dados da tabela você poderia fazer assim:

```
success: function(response) {
    var html = '';

    for(var index in response) {
        html += '<tr>'
                   +'<td>'+response[index].ID+'</td>'
                   +'<td>'+response[index].DESCRICAO+'</td>'
                   +'<td>'
                        +(response[index].VALIDO ? 
                          '<button id="valido" class="sem-validacao">Válido</button>'
                        :
                        'button id="invalido" class="sem-validacao">Inválido</button>')
                  +'</td>'
              +'</tr>'
    }  

   $('tabela tbody').html(html);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela explanação, mas no caso minha dificulde é exatamente de pegar o response e recriar a table no html com os dados atualizado e as linhas com suas respectivas classes `valido` `invalido`

Comment: Você quer atualizar todas as linhas da tabela ou apenas a linha que você está clicando? Qual seria o retorno da url 'updateTelefone.php'?

Comment: A query retornada seria todos os telefones  com `ID`, `Descricao`  e o button  com a classe  `valido` ou `invalido`. Sendo que válido é verde e inválido vermeho.

Comment: Não sei se o ajax atualiza apenas uma linha, por isso penso que terá que retornar a query completa daquele cliente e com javascript renderizar a tabela com os dados do response.

Comment: Editei para atualizar a tabela toda, considerando os dados que você falou.

Comment: Vou testar e amanhã te digo, muito obrigado

Comment: Amigo, muito obrigado pelo seu esforço em me ajudar, porém a ideia do colega acima resolveu meu problema. Fico muito grato por sua ajuda.